# link_to_add_association creating extra forms in a multi-level nested environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, attributes, cocoon-gem

My issue is best described with a picture:
[extra forms added issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ4Yq.png)

Here is the top model:

```
class Profession < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :procedure_categories, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :procedure_categories, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And second:

```
class ProcedureCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profession
  has_many :procedures

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :procedures, allow_destroy: true  
end
```

And third:

```
class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :procedure_category
end
```

Here is where the code is that is causing the issue including the link_to_add_association method.

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :category %>
  <%= f.text_field :category, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :display_order %>
  <%= f.text_field :display_order, class: 'form-control' %>
    <% cs = options_for_select(controls, f.object.selection_type) %>

  <%= f.label :selection_type %>
  <%= f.select :selection_type, cs, class: 'form-control' %>

  <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Display Order</th>
        <th>Selection Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="procedures">
      <%= f.fields_for :procedures do |procedure| %>
        <%= render 'procedure_fields', f: procedure %>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>


  <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Skill', f, :procedures, 
    data: { association_insertion_node: '.procedures', association_insertion_method: :append } %>
  <br><br>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Category", f %>
</div>
```

Finally, here is my partial for rendering Procedures:

```
<tr class="nested-fields">

  <td><%= f.text_field :skill, class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :display_order, class: 'form-control' %></td>

  <td><%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Skill", f %></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you for having a look.

Comment: Class `.procedures` exists twice on your page, correct? (Once under each `Category` block...) And then you're appending to class `.procedures`, yes?

Comment: Ahh, I see now. So, removing this: association_insertion_node: '.procedures' solves the issue, but results in ugly formatting. Do you have a suggestion for how to use association_insertion_node so that I may still keep the formatting?

Comment: Sure. Wrap each `Category` block in a unique `#id` (e.g., `#procedure-category-6` where `6` is assigned dynamically) and then use `#procedure-category-6 .procedures` for targeting your insertion. Or something along those lines. I don't use that `link_to_add_association`, so I have no idea if the syntax will need tweaking.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. How do I give you points for this?

Comment: Added as an answer. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have `.procedures` under each of your `Category` sections. In which case, you're appending to both instances of the `.procedures` class.

You need to create a unique identifier for each `Category` section (e.g., `#procedure-category-6` where 6 is assigned dynamically) and then use `#procedure-category-6 .procedures` for targeting your insertion.